# Ruby core documentation quality

Tags: ruby, documentation

I'm relatively new to Ruby and have limited time therefore I try out simple things.
Recently I needed to create a file and because I'm lazy as hell, I run to Google. The result:

```
File.open(local_filename, 'w') {|f| f.write(doc) }
```

Shame on me, it is very straightforward, should have done it myself. Then I wanted to check what ruby magic the File class' methods offer or if there's any 'simplification' when invoking those methods, so I headed for the documentation [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/), and checked for the File class.

- 1.8.6 documentation presents me with "ftools.rb: Extra tools for the File class" under 'File' class, which is not what I'm looking for.
- 1.8.7 documentation seems OK for 'File' class, there are a plethora of methods. Except 'open'.
- 1.9 documentation finally shows me the 'open' method.

And I had an almost same tour with Net::HTTP.

Do I exaggerate when I think good old Turbo Pascal's 7.0 documentation was better organized than Ruby documentation is right now? Is there any other source for the uninitiated to collect knowledge? Or is it possible that I just tumbled into a documentation hole and the rest are super-brilliant-five-star organized?

Thanks

Comment: With Ruby (and with something called Ruby on Rails), you have to know what to look for. I would agree that the online documentation for both could be immensely better!

Comment: Personally, I almost always go to http://rubydoc.info/ instead of ruby-doc.org. I find it easier to navigate through, and it can generate documentation for gems too (on request). I'm pretty lazy too as it goes.

Comment: @phoffer +1 for rubydoc.info. I hadn't run into that site.

Comment: Thanks for the rubydoc.info site suggestion, it rocks. If I've gone there for the first time, I'd have never written the Question.

Comment: lol. It's a good question. Maybe if a bunch of us throw some volunteer time at rubydoc.info we could get it to be the core doc site for Ruby. I think it has a lot of potential.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to remember that Ruby is an object-oriented language, and a lot of objects in the Standard Library, are built on-top of other objects. In addition, many are extended by modules, which add in new functionality.

So, in the documentation you need to see what things an Object is built-upon. In File's case, it's built on top of [IO](http://www.ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/classes/IO.html), which will have a lot of the functionality you'd expect to find in a standard "file" class.

I agree that some of Ruby's documentation is disjointed. I think it's important to get a good book; I recommend the one we refer to as "The Pickaxe Book", AKA "[Programming Ruby](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0974514055)". There are many other good books, along with some good documentation on line, but this is a great go-to book. The [first edition] is available for free online; It is a bit outdated but still useful.

I'd recommend browsing through [some of the other questions similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2Bruby+%2Bbook) on SO for more suggestions.

I also keep links open to Ruby 1.9's [Core](http://www.ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/index.html) and [Keyword](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/) docs. And, finally, the top of the [Ruby-Docs site](http://www.ruby-doc.org/) points to lots of good info though you do have to pay attention to which version the docs are for.

Finally, don't ignore the built-in help: `ri` at the command-line is a fast source of info on your own machine that should contain documentation for the core and standard library, plus all the gems you have installed. `ri open` would have told you all the places "open" was defined. `ri File.open` would have given you a lot of information about that command.

---

When I started with Ruby, the biggest impediment to learning the language was the documentation. I still find it a lot easier to get info about [Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/) and [Python](http://www.python.org/doc/), and feel like Ruby should use those as examples. That doesn't change my enjoyment of using Ruby though. It's a great language and once getting over the initial hump I like it more and more.

@phoffer recommends [RubyDoc.info](http://rubydoc.info/) in the comment above. I hadn't seen that site but it looks good. I like that it shows what  a class inherits from clearly.

Comment: This answer could be improved. In fact, File#open was left out of Ruby's documentation until 1.9.  If he takes your advice and looks at IO, pre-1.9 all he will see is an open routine that takes a file descriptor. There is a filename-based open documented under Kernel but that's yet another story.

Comment: Pointing to pre-1.9 IO illustrates the OPs point that the docs need organization and cleanup.

Comment: I just recognized I left out the most important info from the question. I currently use "ruby 1.8.7 (2010-06-23 patchlevel 299) [i686-linux]" which is the up-to-date Ubuntu 10.10 ruby version. 'ri File.open' yields "Nothing known about File.open", and with a quick comparison I see that the documentation shown me by 'ri' is the same documentation that is available online as 1.8.7 documentation.

Comment: Yes, sigh, it's an unfortunate state of affairs. I'd recommend using the docs at http://rubydoc.info/

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, there is a bug in the pre-1.9 documentation regarding `File#open`.

There is an `open` documented under `Kernel`, and yes, you can in fact say `File.open` as you noted, it just isn't documented either in `File` or in `IO`.

My advice is to just [***use 1.9 docs***](http://www.ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/index.html)...

Answer (score 0):

My current version is ruby 2.0.0 and ri 4.0.1 (ri -v). I have been stumbling with the same problem where I type ri File.open => "Nothing known about File.open"

After scourging the internet I found this code [Source](http://www.jstorimer.com/blogs/workingwithcode/7766081-5-reasons-you-should-use-ri-to-read-ruby-documentation)

```
gem rdoc --all --ri --no-rdoc
```

The page is also a good read to why you should use ri instead of google.

Edit: The code fixed the "Nothing known about File.open" yield. It takes some time to install so open a new tab.